# Is the firmware update for APFS on an older Mac on disk or NVRAM?

Tags: mac-pro, apfs, firmware

My 2008 MacPro3,1 is getting long in the tooth and one of the few things left I can do for it before retiring it is to set APFS as the system drive so that I can attempt to run Mojave on it. However, I've been hesitant so far because it appears to be somewhat of a hack to get this machine to boot an APFS volume. Specifically, it appears that you need to [update the firmware](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GOl5nxQ4eM) to make it possible to boot an APFS drive.

My question is, when doing this modification, is it updating the firmware on the motherboard (some NVRAM / flash ROM) or is this installed on the boot drive in the UEFI partition? If it is on the boot drive, I am less worried since you can always reformat the drive. However, if it is on the motherboard firmware, I'm concerned about usability of the machine going forward (e.g. reinstalling an older OS or possibly converting the machine into a Windows 10 or Linux machine).

Comment: I really wouldn't put Mojave on a 3,1. Just don't. They are simply not fast enough for it & even if you've a high-end [for the time] GPU HD 5xxx or 6xxx you won't get hardware acceleration, without which it will grind to a halt. Leave it on El Cap.

Comment: Your best option if you want macOS Mojave is to install it on an external SSD using another computer running macOS Mojave or macOS High Sierra. Then use the Install macOS Mojave application from the App Store to install on the External SSD and see how good your experience is. DON'T TAMPER WITH YOUR CURRENT STARTUP DISK!!! I can't stress that enough because macOS Mojave on an older computer's default startup disk may not be a good idea.